# Updating Active Class on Navbar using MDBootstrap and nav.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mdbootstrap

I am trying to update the *active* class on my navbar using MDBootstrap by checking the current href so that it signifies which page the user is currently on. I can successfully set the class to *active* in an individual list item in the code below, but it will not update when I choose another navbar option on the browser. I have tried all snippets of js code found on Stackoverflow to no avail. For context, all of my navbar code is in one file, **nav.php**, and is being loaded into all other files.

**How I'm loading the navbar into each php file which works perfectly:**

```
<div id="nav-placeholder">
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.php");
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** I am no longer loading **nav.php** using the code above, I am simply using `<?php include_once "nav.php";?>` at the top of each PHP file.

**nav.php:**

```
<!-- header.php includes all the relevant CDN links for MDBootStrap 4.19.1 -->
<?php include_once "header.php";?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<nav class="mb-1 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark default-color" id="nav-placeholder">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-333"
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-333" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-333">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/about.php">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/apply.php">Apply Now</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/contact.php">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>     
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Make sure that upon execution of the js, 'active' isn't being nullified -->
<script>
$(function(){
    var current = location.pathname;
    $('#nav li').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // if the current path is like this link, make it active
        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    })
})
</script>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help you may have to offer, I am sure I am overlooking something or am unaware of some critical knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: `$(function(){})` executed when the intial DOM is loaded, I doubt it executes again, if you insert it into the existing document via `.load()`

Comment: Good point! I removed the `.load()` code chunk and instead included **nav.php** at the top of each PHP file using `include_once`. I also tried putting the script snippet into each PHP file instead of just **nav.php**. This, however, still did not fix the problem.